# MVC label with span condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

Is there another way to write this? I only want to display the span if in the model the `IsRequired` is true?

```
<label for=pollingResponses[{0}].Value)> @Html.Raw(@item.labelControl)
if (@item.IsRequired)
     {
         <span class="required"></span>
     }
</label>
```

Comment: Is your property define as "bool" type in your model ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string variable to add **bootstrap class** for your *span* tag, if your condition is not true your *span* has ***hide*** **bootstrap class**.

```
@{
    string hideSpan ='hide';
    if (item.IsRequired)
        hideSpan = '';        
}
<label for=pollingResponses[{0}].Value)> @Html.Raw(@item.labelControl)

         <span class="required @hideSpan"></span>
</label>
```